Joint probability of a Brownian Motion
Example 3.1 from Introduction to Stochastic Calculus with Applications by Klebaner, 1st edition
Problem: For Brownian motion $B(t)$, with $B(0) = 0$, find: $$P(B(0) \le 0, B(1) \le 0, B(2) \le 0)$$
I’m having difficulty understanding the following step:
Let $\hat B(1) = B(2)- B(1)$
It’s suggested by "conditioning and by using Theorem 2.21 and (2.17)"
$$P(B(1) \le 0, \hat B(1) \le -B(1)) = \int_{-\infty}^0 P(\hat B(1) \le -x) f(x) dx$$
Theorem 2.21:
Let X and Y be two independent random variables and $\phi(x,y)$ be such that $E|(\phi(X,Y)| \lt +\infty$. Then $$E(\phi(X,Y)|Y) = G(Y),$$ where $G(y) = E(\phi(X,y))$
Theorem (2.17)
For some field $\mathcal G$: $$E(E(X|\mathcal G)) = EX$$
I don’t really understand how these equations help but I’m guessing the comment on conditioning means:
$$P(B(1) \le 0, \hat B(1) \le -B(1)) = P(\hat B(1) \le -B(1) | B(1) \le 0) P(B(1) \le 0)$$
So then the problem becomes finding: $$P(\hat B(1) \le -B(1) | B(1) \le 0)$$
The only thing with expectations I can think of that might be related is $P(A) = E(I_A)$, but I don’t really see how it might help

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Thank you for the references

The conditional probablity
$$\tag1
\mathbb P\left(\hat B_1\le -B_1\Big|B_1 \right)
$$
in the measure theoretic sense can be written as a function of $B_1$
and one can use that $\hat B_1$ and $B_1$ are independent. Then, (1) is
$$\tag2
\mathbb P\left(\hat B_1\le -x\right)\Big|_{x=B_1}
$$
which we can evaluate easily for every $x$ because $\hat B_1\sim N(0,1)\,:$
$$\tag3
\mathbb P\left(\hat B_1\le -x\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{-x}\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}\,dy\,.
$$
By the tower property,
\begin{align}
&\mathbb P\left(B_1\le 0,B_2\le 0\right)=
\mathbb P\left(B_1\le 0,\hat B_1\le -B_1\right)\\[2mm]&=
\mathbb E\Big[\mathbb E\Big[\underbrace{1_{\{B_1\le 0\}}}_{\sigma(B_1)\text{-measurable}}1_{\{\hat B_1\le -B_1\}}\Big|B_1\Big]\Big]\\[2mm]
&=\mathbb E\left[1_{\{B_1\le 0\}}\mathbb E\left[1_{\{\hat B_1\le -B_1\}}\Big|B_1\right]\right]
=\mathbb E\left[1_{\{B_1\le 0\}}\mathbb P\left(\hat B_1\le -B_1\Big|B_1\right)\right]\,.\tag4
\end{align}
Using (2) and (3) this is
$$\tag5\boxed{\phantom{\Big|}
\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^{-x}\frac 1{2\pi}e^{-(y^2+x^2)/2}\,dy\,dx\,.\quad}
$$
Another Approach
Using the notation
$$
\operatorname{Var}(B_1)=1\,,\quad\operatorname{Var}(B_2)=2=:\sigma^2\,,\quad\operatorname{Corr}(B_1,B_2)=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}:=\varrho\,
$$
and the PDF of the bivariate normal distribution we get
\begin{align}
&\mathbb P\big(B_1\le 0,B_2\le 0\big)\\[2mm]
&=\frac1{2\pi\sigma\sqrt{1-\varrho^2}}\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^0\exp\left(-\frac{\sigma^2x^2+y^2-2\varrho\sigma xy}{2(1-\rho^2)\sigma^2}\right)\,dy\,dx\\[2mm]
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^0\exp\left(-\frac{2x^2+y^2-2xy}{2}\right)\,dy\,dx\\[2mm]
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-\infty}^0\exp\left(-\frac{x^2+(y-x)^2}{2}\right)\,dy\,dx\,.\tag{6}
\end{align}
After a variable transformation $y-x\mapsto y$ this becomes equal to (5).

Thank you for the reply. In (2) could you elaborate on where the inequality on $B_1$ went. In (3) is the top bound on the integration not supposed to be -x? I'm not sure your result matches the integral in my post

@user3093591 yes there was $-x$ missing in (3) and (5). Fixed. In (2) and (3) we don't consider the inequality on $B_1$ yet. This is postponed until we bring it back in (4) and use the tower property.

Ok that makes more sense. I'm still finding the techniques you've used more advanced than what I've been introduced to in the text. Did you use Jensen's inequality? I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to take on this problem. Could you elaborate on (4), that line seems unconnected to the rest. Are you using independence and  $g(X) = I_B h(X)$ $E(g(X)) = \int_\Omega g(x) dF = \int_B h(x) dF$?

@user3093591 I did not use Jensen's inequality as we are trying to show an equality. Further, I did my best to elaborate on (4). You should digest it all again. For the future: If you use formulas as in your last comment you should explain your notation.

Yes, that's true, so why would the author suggest it? Perhaps using the case where it's an equality? My apologies for the ambiguity: $g(X): \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ and $B \subseteq \Bbb R$. Thank you for your insight, your time and efforts are much appreciated

@user3093591 Klebaner did not suggest to use the Jensen inequality. His approach corresponds exactly to what I elaborated on. Whoever downvoted this answer may stew in their toxic goulash of their own making.

From pg. 57 of the text referring to the integral equation in my original question: "By conditioning and by using Theorem 2.21 and (2.17)". 2.17 is the law of double expectation and 2,21 refers to a special case of Jensen's inequality for the absolute value function.

I always find it lovely when one thinks I am running around with the exact same book under my arm all day. Found only the 3rd edition where most things have different numbers. Quote them fully in OP to enable a fruitful discussion.

I'm confused by your statement. I stated the edition I was working from and provided the equations in the OP

In the third edition, Klebaner mentions Theorem 2.24 and equation (2.20). The Theorem 2.24 is exactly the property of conditional expectation that I used in my link and not Jensen's inequality or a special case thereof. Equation (2.20) is the tower law that I also used.

You are confused because you seem to believe that I am running around with the first edition all day.

Haha, no I'm confused because there seems to be an error in the text I'm working from. Thank you again and enjoy the rest of your weekend

Could be. Most likely a typo in the numbering. Happens a lot.

Looks like I was confusing 2.21 with (2.21). I've edited the OP to reflect that

Let $Z_1=B(1)$, and let $Z_2=B(2)-B(1)$. The properties of Brownian motion imply that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are independent standard normal variables. In terms of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$, you want to find the probability of the event
$$
\{Z_1\le 0\}\cap \{Z_1+Z_2\le 0\}.
$$
This event occurs if and only if the point $(Z_1,Z_2)$ lies in the region $R$ of the Euclidean plane, defined by
$$
R=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2\mid x\le 0,x+y\le 0\}
$$
Note that $R$ is an angular sector whose angle is $3/8\cdot 2\pi$ radians. Since the joint distribution of $(Z_1,Z_2)$ is rotationally symmetric, this implies that $P((Z_1,Z_2)\in R)=\boxed{3/8}$.

This is a very elegant solution! However I don't think it's what the author was arguing in the text
